# How is Stromberg Wavelet S orthogonal to Simple tents?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, wavelets

$\newcommand{\inprod}[2]{\left\langle{#1}\,|\,{#2}\right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\setn}[1]{{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}$
$\newcommand{\setu}{\cup}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brbl}[1]{\left\{#1\right.}$
How do they come about the difference equation when demonstrating a Strömberg wavelet $S(t)$ is orthogonal to a *simple tent function*
$$\lambda_{\sigma}(t) \eqd \brbl{\begin{array}{ll} 
      1             & \text{if $t=\sigma$}
    \\0             & \text{if $t\in A_0$ and $t\neq\sigma$}
    \\\text{linear} & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}}$$
in the computation of the Strömberg Wavelet? Here,
$$\begin{array}{lcll}
  A_0 &\eqd& \setn{\cdots,-\frac{3}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},0,1,2,3,\cdots}&\text{and moreover}\\
  A_1 &\eqd& A_0 \setu \setn{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{array}$$
In particular, how can we arrive at this set of equations?
$$0 = \inprod{S}{\lambda_{\sigma }} = 
  \brbl{\begin{array}{l ll}
    S\brp{\sigma -1}+ 4S\brp{\sigma}+S\brp{\sigma +1}
    &   \text{for $\sigma\in\setn{2,3,4,\ldots}$} 
    &   \text{(1.10)}
    \\
    S\brp{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}+ 4S\brp{\sigma}+S\brp{\sigma+\frac{1}{2}}
    &   \text{for $\sigma\in\setn{-\frac{1}{2},-1,-\frac{3}{2},-2,\ldots}$} 
    &   \text{(1.11)}
    \\
    2S\brp{-\frac{1}{2}} + 9S\brp{0} + 6S\brp{\frac{1}{2}} + S\brp{1}
    &   \text{for $\sigma=0$}
    &  \text{(1.12)}
    \\
    S\brp{0} + 6S\brp{\frac{1}{2}} + 13S\brp{1} + 4S\brp{2}
    &   \text{for $\sigma=1$}
    &  \text{(1.13)}
\end{array}}$$

You can check the equations (1.10)–(1.13) [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJ8QtFuEo1knBqNkkbrcGDyAThEA1fg0/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Muhammed—It's a good question... I'm not sure why it was voted down (without explanation) previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\inprod}[2]{\left\langle{#1}\,|\,{#2}\right\rangle}$
$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\setn}[1]{{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}$
$\newcommand{\setu}{\cup}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brbl}[1]{\left\{#1\right.}$
$\newcommand{\intcc} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{{\;dx}}$
I don't have a huge background in Strömberg Wavelets$\ldots$ but assuming the equation for (1.10) is correct, it should be possible to prove it by writing down the equations for $\Lambda_\sigma$ and $S(\sigma)$ and integrate their product over $\sigma-1\leq t\leq\sigma+1$. In particular, note that for $\sigma\in\setn{2,3,4,\ldots}$
$$\Lambda_{\sigma}(x) = \brbl{\begin{array}{ll} 
      1-\sigma+x   & \text{for $\sigma-1\leq x\leq\sigma$}
    \\1+\sigma-x   & \text{for $\sigma\leq x\leq\sigma+1$}
    \\0            & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}}$$
and
$$S(x) = \brbl{\begin{array}{ll} 
      \frac{S(\sigma)-S(\sigma-1)}{1}\brp{x-\sigma}+S(\sigma) & \text{for $\sigma-1\leq x\leq\sigma$}
    \\\frac{S(\sigma+1)-S(\sigma)}{1}\brp{x-\sigma}+S(\sigma) & \text{for $\sigma\leq x\leq\sigma+1$}
\end{array}}$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}
  \inprod{S(x)}{\lambda_\sigma(x)}
    &= \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}}S(x)\lambda_\sigma(x)dx
    && \text{by definition of $\inprod{f(x)}{g(x)}$}
  \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma+1}S(x)\lambda_\sigma(x)dx
    && \text{because support of $\lambda_\sigma$ is $\intcc{\sigma-1}{\sigma+1}$}
  \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}S(x)\lambda_\sigma(x)dx
     + \int_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1}S(x)\lambda_\sigma(x)dx
\end{align*}$$

Actually, for the case $\sigma\in\setn{2,3,4,\ldots}$, I get a similar result as the linked reference, but different by a factor of $\frac{1}{6}$:

(lemma 1):
$$    \begin{align}
        &\int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}   \brs{ (A-B)(x-\sigma)+A           } (1-\sigma+x)    \dx
    \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}   \brs{ A(1-\sigma+x) + B(\sigma-x) } (1-\sigma+x)    \dx
    \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}  A\brs{ x^2 + 2x(1-\sigma)        + (1-\sigma)^2    } + B\brs{-x^2 +  x(\sigma+\sigma-1) + \sigma(1-\sigma)} \dx
    \\&= \brs{ A\brs{ \frac{1}{3}x^3 +             x^2(1-\sigma ) + x(1-\sigma)^2    } + B\brs{-\frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2} x^2(2\sigma-1) + x\sigma(1-\sigma)}}_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}
    \\&= A\brs{ \frac{1}{3}\brp{\sigma^3-\brp{\sigma^3-3\sigma^2+3\sigma-1}} +            \brp{\sigma^2-\brp{\sigma^2-2\sigma+1}}(1-\sigma ) + (1-\sigma)^2\brp{\sigma-(\sigma-1)} }
\\&+ B\brs{-\frac{1}{3}\brp{\sigma^3-\brp{\sigma^3-3\sigma^2+3\sigma-1}} + \frac{1}{2}\brp{\sigma^2-\brp{\sigma^2-2\sigma+1}}(2\sigma-1) + \sigma(1-\sigma)}
\\&= A\brs{\brp{\sigma^2 - \sigma + \frac{1}{3} } +(2\sigma-1)(1-\sigma)+(-\sigma+1)^2}
\\&+B\brs{-\brp{\sigma^2 - \sigma + \frac{1}{3}} + \frac{1}{2}(2\sigma-1)(2\sigma-1) + \sigma(-\sigma+1)}
\\&=A\brs{\sigma^2( 1-2+1)+\sigma(-1+2+1-2)+\brp{ \frac{1}{3}-1+1}}
\\&+B\brs{\sigma^2(-1+2-1) + \sigma( 1-1-1+1) + \brp{-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}}
\\&= \boxed{\frac{1}{3}A + \frac{1}{6}B}
\end{align}$$

(lemma 2):
$$\begin{align}
  &\int_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1}  \brs{ (C-A)(x-\sigma)+C      } (1+\sigma-x)  \dx
\\&= \int_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1}  \brs{ C(1-\sigma+x) + A(\sigma-x) } (1+\sigma-x)  \dx
\\&= \int_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1} C\brs{-x^2 + x(\sigma+\sigma+1) + \sigma(-\sigma-1)  } 
\\&+ A\brs{ x^2 + x(-\sigma-1-1-\sigma) + (1+\sigma)^2} \dx
\\&= \brs{ C\brs{-\frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2} x^2(2\sigma+1) - x\sigma(\sigma+1)} +A\brs{ \frac{1}{3}x^3 -       x^2( \sigma+1) + x(\sigma+1)^2  }}_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1}
\\&= C\brs{-\frac{1}{3}\brp{\brp{\sigma^3+3\sigma^2+3\sigma+1}-\sigma^3} + \frac{1}{2}\brp{\brp{\sigma^2+2\sigma+1}-\sigma^2}(2\sigma+1) - \sigma(\sigma+1) }
\\&+ A\brs{ \frac{1}{3}\brp{\brp{\sigma^3+3\sigma^2+3\sigma+1}-\sigma^3} -      \brp{\brp{\sigma^2+2\sigma+1}-\sigma^2}( \sigma+1) + (\sigma+1)^2   }
\\&= C\brs{-\sigma^2 + \sigma - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}(2\sigma+1)(2\sigma+1) - \sigma^2 -\sigma } 
\\&+ A\brs{ \sigma^2 + \sigma + \frac{1}{3} - (2\sigma+1)( \sigma+1) + \sigma^2 + 2\sigma + 1   }
\\&= C\brs{\sigma^2(-1+2-1) + \sigma(-1+1+1-1) + \brp{-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}} \\&+ A\brs{\sigma^2( 1-2+1) + \sigma( 1-2-1+2) + \brp{ \frac{1}{3}-1+1}}
\\&= \boxed{\frac{1}{6}C + \frac{1}{3}A}
\end{align}$$

(definitions): Let $A\eqd S(\sigma)$, $B\eqd S(\sigma-1)$, and $C\eqd S(\sigma+1)$.

Then$\ldots$
$$\begin{align}
  \inprod{S(x)}{\Lambda_\sigma(x)}
    &= \int_{x\in\mathbb{R}}S(x)\Lambda_\sigma(x)\dx
    && \text{by definition of $\inprod{f(x)}{g(x)}$}
  \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma+1}S(x)\Lambda_\sigma(x)\dx
    && \text{because support of $\Lambda_\sigma$ is $\intcc{\sigma-1}{\sigma+1}$}
  \\&= \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma}S(x)\Lambda_\sigma(x)\dx + \int_{x=\sigma}^{x=\sigma+1}S(x)\Lambda_\sigma(x)\dx
  \\&\eqd \int_{x=\sigma-1}^{x=\sigma  } \brs{ (A-B)(x-\sigma)+A } (1-\sigma+x) \dx
   \\&+ \int_{x=\sigma  }^{x=\sigma+1} \brs{ (C-A)(x-\sigma)+C } (1+\sigma-x) \dx
    && \text{by (definitions)}
  \\&= \brs{\frac{1}{3}A + \frac{1}{6}B} + \brs{\frac{1}{6}C + \frac{1}{3}A}
    && \text{by (lemma 1) and (lemma 2)}
  \\&= \frac{1}{6}\brs{B + 4A + C}
  \\&\eqd \boxed{\frac{1}{6}\brs{S(\sigma-1) + 4S(\sigma) + S(\sigma+1)}}
    && \text{by (definitions)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I would like to know the reason why we integrated to respect of x, and not on the initial given t.

Comment: I also believe that the factor 1/6 would vanish since we have an orthogonal system, that is equal to zero.


Multiply through the factor 1/6 would give the same referenced answer.

Comment: Integration can be carried out with respect to any variable that you may chose—t, x, ω, y. It's just a matter of aesthetics (math is a form of art, and what looks good is a matter of opinion). According to the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), whatever variable you used will disappear and be replaced by what is in the limits of integration: $\int_a^b f(t)dt = \int_a^b f(x)dx = F(b)-F(a)$ where F is the anti-derivative of f in [a,b]. That is, the result of the integration is the same regardless of choice of $x$ or $t$.

Comment: If the values of $S(\sigma)$ are chosen such that the system is orthogonal to the simple tent functions $\Lambda_{\sigma}$, then the $\frac{1}{6}$ can vanish, along with the entire factor $\left[S(\sigma-1)+4S(\sigma)+S(\sigma+1)\right]$. However, in the (possibly flawed) proof I offered above, I don't assume that such special values of $S(\sigma)$ have been chosen.

Comment: This is helpful. I was trying to create a simple tent functions for the case when \text{for $\sigma\in\setn{-\frac{1}{2},-1,-\frac{3{2},-2,\ldots}$} 
   
Any help on this?

Comment: That can be a little tricky,$\ldots$ but the [point slope form](https://archive.org/details/analyticgeometr00tracgoog/page/n57/) equation of the line is helpful: The point at the peak of $y\triangleq\Lambda_{\sigma}(x)$ is $(x_1,y_1)=(\sigma,1)$. So an equation for the simple tent "going up" in $\sigma\in\left\{\ldots, -\frac{5}{2}, -2, -\frac{3}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ is $$y=m(x-x_1)+y_1=\frac{1-0}{1/2}(x-\sigma)+1=2(x-\sigma)+1$$ and an equation for the simple tent "going down" is $$y=m(x-x_1)+y_1=\frac{0-1}{1/2}(x-\sigma)+1=-2(x-\sigma)+1$$